# Android view updater thread allowing view to update only once every N milliseconds and only on demand

Tags: java, multithreading, invalidation, throttling

I have a thread that I'd like to wait for events on.  When this thread is notified, I'd like it to wake up and if it's been longer than REFRESH_TIME, then it will invalidate a view with a call to postInvalidate.  Otherwise it will sleep for the time it takes to fall on the next REFRESH_TIME.  Meanwhile, if other events try to notify it to draw, some flag should be set so that it immediately redraws again after the next REFRESH_TIME passes again.  Otherwise, it will wait indefinitely until next notify (or requested to stop of course, but ignore that part for simplicity).

I was trying to develop this within a synchronized lock with wait and notify and it doesn't seem like I can use just that.  WaitForSingleObject with a timeout comes to mind for c++, but in java I haven't had the chance to do something similar yet.  What would one use for this that would best suit the problem?

If I get 100 notifications while running an update, I should treat them as a single notify and add just one more invalidate, falling REFRESH_TIME milliseconds after the next one.  In other words.  Updates cannot be missed.

Here's some incomplete code.  How could I finish it?

```
public class ViewInvalidator extends Thread {

private View m_view;

Object lock = new Object();
boolean ready = false;
long m_refreshTimeMilliseconds;
boolean m_threadRequestedToStop = false;

public ViewInvalidator(View view, long refreshTimeMilliseconds) {

    m_view = view;
    m_refreshTimeMilliseconds = refreshTimeMilliseconds;
}

public void postInvalidate() {

    synchronized(lock) {

        ready = true;
        lock.notifyAll();
    }
}

public void stopThread() {

    synchronized (lock) {

        while(!ready)
            lock.notifyAll();
    }
}

@Override
public void run() {

    long lastPostInvalidate = System.currentTimeMillis(), timeSince;

    while(true) {

        if (this.m_threadRequestedToStop)
            break;

        try {

            synchronized (lock) {

                while (!ready)
                    lock.wait();

            }
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {

            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            break;
        }

        // someone just woke us up.  Check if it was a request to stop.  If it was, stop.
        if (this.m_threadRequestedToStop)
            break;

        // if less time than our refresh time, sleep for the difference, then invalidate.  Otherwise just invalidate.
        timeSince = System.currentTimeMillis() - lastPostInvalidate;
        if(timeSince < m_refreshTimeMilliseconds)
            try {
                Thread.sleep(m_refreshTimeMilliseconds - timeSince);
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {}

        m_view.postInvalidate();
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot,
Mike

Comment: Can you describe the purpose of this thread in any more detail? It's currently unclear why you need this thread as opposed to just using blocking or timers

Comment: I've got a bunch of threads responsible for updating the ui separately. I want to conglomerate their calls so that they don't needlessly call invalidate when not separated by REFRESH_TIME.  The updater thread will do it and cancel the extra ones in between, treating them as 1, so that the individual threads can just say that they need a redraw.

Comment: I understand that part but there doesn't seem to be a reason why you can't just use a boolean for invalid and check it whenever your program would normally redraw

Comment: I don't see it.  Any idea how to modify the code I added to the question?

Comment: I'll explore your code more tomorrow evening, but for starters, there's no sleep yet, and that has to happen somewhere I think...  my own sleep will help as well. I'm zonked. :)

Comment: I love the simplicity of your try on this, but it's missing an update at the end so it won't work. While within the ignore phase, the view will have changed and the redraw won't be triggered.

Comment: sorry I forgot that use case, was busy with other things and only half focused at the time(I think it's fixed now). I guess the most useful thing to know about your program would be the information about how you are expecting it will be used. Your question involves odd behavior so It would be useful to know why you wanted it to work that way. Need to know more about how often you expect it to be updated and in what sort of pattern to understand why you wanted it to function the way you described.

Answer (score 0):

```
long lastPostInvalidate;
bool running;
bool valid;

public void f(){
if(running)if(!valid)synchronized(valid){valid=true;}
else {
running = true;
while(func()){};
running = false;
}

private bool func() {
synchronized (valid){valid = false;}
synchronized (lastPostInvalidate) {
long next = System.currentTimeMillis();
long x = next - timeSincelastPostInvalidate;
x = m_refreshTimeMilliseconds-x;
if(x>0)sleep(x);
m_view.postInvalidate();
timeSincelastPostInvalidate = next;
}return valid;
}
```

Forgot that use condition. It should actually have looked like this. That said, doing it this way could potentially lock your updating thread if you are expecting to frequently update mid-update, which would matter if you were also using those threads for other things. If you expect updates that frequently though, you might as well use the thread as you originally planned but not have it deactivate and just check every interval if it needs to run or not.